# Not able to add spark job on EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I am able to  launch, manage and shut down Spark clusters on Amazon EC2 from http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/ec2-scripts.html.

But I am not able to add below job on cluster.

```scala
package spark.examples

import spark.SparkContext
import SparkContext._

object SimpleJob {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "< Amazon S3 file url>"
    val sc = new SparkContext(
      "spark://<Host Name>:7077", 
      "Simple Job",
      System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), Seq("<Jar Address>")
    )
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile)
    val numsa = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count
    val numsb = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count
    println("total a : %s, total b : %s".format(numsa, numsb))
  }

}
```

I have created a SimpleJob.scala and added in spark.examples package on my local spark directory. After that I run the command:

```sh
./spark-ec2 -k <keypair> -i <key-file> login <cluster-name>
```

Cluster is started and I am able to login in cluster.
But I don't know how to add and run this job on EC2 cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try first to run it locally, once you achieve that you will have a better idea of the process involved. Follow the instructions [here](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) in the section "***A standalone job in Scala***". Then copy the script to the remote machine and run the script from there with:

```
./run spark.examples.SimpleJob
```

IF you try to connect to your remote spark from the local script with:

```
MASTER=spark://ec2-174-129-181-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 ./run spark.examples.SimpleJob
```

the most probably result is that you will get a connection error as port 7077 is blocked by default in EC2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to run it locally. I followed all the instructions mentioned here:

http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: I am able to launch cluster on Amazon-ec2. But When I go to my spark directory and run:
        `MASTER=spark://ec2-174-129-181-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 ./run spark.examples.SimpleJob`

I am getting below message on console:

        `13/09/09 15:11:31 WARN cluster.ClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered`
`13/09/09 15:11:46 WARN cluster.ClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered`

Comment: When I hit ec2-174-129-181-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080 on my browser, I am able to see one worker and no running application.  Please let me know If I am missing anything.

Comment: are you running the ./run command from the shell in the remote or the local machine? Do you have any other spark-shell open which could be using the resources?

Comment: After launching cluster, I got spark master url on the bottom of console.  
Suppose url is spark://ec2-174-129-181-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077.   I added this url in 'master' field of spark context of my SimpleJob.scala.  After that, I went to spark directory on my local machine and ran sbt/sbt package.  Then I ran :  
                                                                                                         :~/spark$ MASTER=spark://ec2-174-129-181-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 ./run spark.examples.SimpleJob

Comment: most probably Amazon blocks connections from your local machine to the port 7077. Copy the script, ssh and try repeating those steps in the remote machine.

Comment: I went to `/spark/ec2 directory` on my local machine and run :    `./spark-ec2 -k sparktest -i sparktest.pem login sparktest` .    After that, When I ran `ls` command to see list of directory, I am able to see :
`ephemeral-hdfs  hive  mesos  mesos-ec2  persistent-hdfs  scala-2.9.3  shark  spark  spark-ec2` ..  Then I typed `cd spark`. After that, I typed: `[root@domU-12-31-39-16-32-EC spark]# MASTER=spark://ec2-174-129-181-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 ./run spark.examples.SimpleJob
`    This time, I am getting below error: `Error: Could not find or load main class spark.examples.SimpleJob`

Comment: I also tried to open port from EC2 security group firewall. I selected `sparktest-master` group id and create a `Custom TCP Rule`. I gave range 7077 and source as 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: You can try opening the ports but I wouldn't go that way. Try copying or creating the script in the remote machine, build with sbt like in the local machine and then run there.

Comment: Thanks a ton Elyase for resolving my issue. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: glad to help, if there is any other detail I should add to help others in the future please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to run locally, then, most probably the issue can be Spark workers are not able to access your jar. Let me know if the following steps work-

1. Export your code into a jar file (I usually use Eclipse but you can use sbt too)
2. Run the command at master as

   ```
   SPARK_CLASSPATH=<path/to/jar/file> ./run <Class> [arguements]
   ```

For example,

```
    SPARK_CLASSPATH=Simple.jar ./run spark.examples.SimpleJob
```

Also make sure your workers are alive from Spark master UI. Hope this helps!